# How to pass the output of a command as argument in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a C program that accepts arguments. I want to pass arguments to it while debugging through gdb but I want to specify the arguments through, say, a python command. So,

`(gdb) run >>python return "a"*20 #arg1 >>python return 1+2 #arg2`

How can I do this? The reason why I want to do this is because I want to pass bytecode address to the program as an argument but if I pass it as a sting it just converts everything to ASCII. i.e. if I try:

`(gdb) run \xf7\xff\xba\xb5`

then the address that I gave above is just converted into an ASCII string instead of being used as a memory address. I think if my first query is answered my second query might also get answered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution.

`` (gdb) run "`python -c 'print "\xff\xff\xff\xff"'`" ``